# Autofocus in a modal Angular 4 doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have to focus the input at the loading of a modal but if I use the html5 attribute `autofocus` it seems not working.
Is it possible to make it works?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label">
    {{'ticketbundle.busroutedetail.dialog.labels.buslinename'
     | translate }}<span class="star">*</span>
   </label><input autofocus class="form-control" id="name" required
   [(ngModel)]="busRouteDetail.name" name="name" #busRouteDetailname>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am using angular material 2

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the Material Dialog, you can use `cdkFocusInitial` to specify where you want initial focus to be.

```
<input cdkFocusInitial type="text">
```

See this [**EXAMPLE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta11-hbq2vh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: This is now deprecated and the new directive is called cdkFocusInitial. But do you know if this only works when using the dialog component of angular material itself or should this focus directive also work alone on any other modal component? I at least thought so since it is available in the anguluar/cdk package, but I can not get it to work with a ngbootstrap modal

Comment: I had to double check the source, but the `cdkFocusInitial` attribute doesn't actually manage any logic. It's just there as a place-marker when using `cdkTrapFocus`

Comment: In order to get `cdkFocusInitial` to work outside of the Material components that have it baked in (MatDialog, MatBottomSheet, MatSidenav), it must be contained in an element that has both `cdkTrapFocus` (as per @WillHowell), and `cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ngbAutofocus` on the element you want to focus.

See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#focus

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular Material version 13.1.3. With the bottom sheet component, `cdkFocusInitial` wasn't working for me unless I set the `autoFocus` config option as well;

```
this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetComponent, {
  autoFocus: true
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you could set a local template ref with `#myInput` and access the element with `@ViewChild() myInput` in your ts file, and in the hook `ngAfterViewInit` get the native element and set the focus property with
`this.myInput.nativeElement.focus()`

another option is to build a focus directive and bind it to the focus attribute of the element [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307060/how-to-set-focus-on-element-with-binding)

Comment: This does not work: ngAfterViewInit fires too soon.