# how to set focus for AutoComplete component from PrimeNG library in Angular

Tags: angular, html, typescript, primeng

I am trying to use a AutoCompete component inside a Dialog element. I want the focus goes to the AutoComplement element when the Diaglog opens.

I have not find a exact tutorial on this.

My effect is based on this stackoverflow link:
[How to use Angular4 to set focus by element id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720611/how-to-use-angular4-to-set-focus-by-element-id/46720813)

And this Github issue:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2029
Although I do not understand some part like the onAfterShow event, and some guy in that thread tried and does not work.

My code goes like this(simplified):

Component

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="this.display" modal="true"(onShow)="this.onAfterShow($event)">
  <p-autoComplete  #autoCompleteObject>
  </p-autoComplete>
  <some-other-components>
<p-dialog>
```

TypeScript:

```
  @ViewChild('autoCompleteObject') private autoCompleteObject: AutoComplete ;
  onAfterShow(event){   this.autoCompleteObject.domHandler.findSingle(this.autoCompleteObject.el.nativeElement, 'input').focus();
  }
```

or like that:

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteObject', {read: ElementRef}) private autoCompleteObject: ElementRef ;
  onAfterShow(event){
    console.log("diaglog shows");
    this.autoCompleteObject.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

When when the diaglog opens, the onAfterShow() function is executed without error. 
However, the focus is not set on the autocomplete element.

Any suggestions where I got it wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each `autocomplete` instance has a public function [`focusInput()`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L457). Once you have a reference to your instance via `@ViewChild('autoCompleteObject')...`, you can call `focusInput()` on this reference:

```
onAfterShow(event) {
  this.autoCompleteObject.focusInput();
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqjyix?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**UPDATE**

This is related to primeng v1.0.xxx:
In order to manually control focus within dialog add `[focusOnShow]="false"`:

```
<p-dialog header="Title" 
          [focusOnShow]="false" 
          [(visible)]="display" 
          modal="true" 
          (onShow)="onAfterShow()">
   ...
</p-dialog>
```

this way, the button does not "steal" the focus, STACKBLITZ updated

Comment: I believe it's a valid solution, but for some unknown reason it still does not work for me.

Comment: please update my or create a new stackblitz with non-working version and I will try to help

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmce7e?file=src/app/app.component.html.   Adding a button, the focus is no longer on the p-autocomplete component.

Comment: it is weird, button "steals" a focus from the input, as a workaround you can add `focus` to your button like `<button (focus)="onAfterShow()">test</button>`. I do not like this workaround, but it is the only one I thought of. Please note that this will cancel tab selection (pressing TAB to select button while input is focused). I updated my stackblitz