# nativeElement.select(); only works on a setTimeout | angular

Tags: angular

On the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle in angular, I'd like to `focus()` and `select()` the input. I've played around with it a bit and it seems like `select()` only works after I set a timeout. For example, the code below works as intended (input is focused and selected).

```
<input #el>
```

---

```
@ViewChild('el') el;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      this.el.nativeElement.select();
    }, 0);
  }
```

But just doing this, only `focus` works.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    this.el.nativeElement.select();
  }
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: I suppose you are using Firefox? I had the same problem and it depends on the browser used. In Chrome it works without timeout, but in other browsers such as Firefox (and I think Edge), it doesn't. I don't have an explanation though.

Comment: check this answer on the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520856/606104