# How to focus on top anchor tag in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my application, I'm navigating from home to banner component. Then anchor tag in a banner component not getting focus on tab click prior to the footer anchor tag.

*And yes I want to focus anchor tag on tab click, not on the page load.*

when I refresh a banner component it works fine.
The problem comes when a user navigates from home to the banner component then it's not working properly.

**[There](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe2mzc) is running demo app.**

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: '',
          component: HomeComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'banner',
          component: BannerComponent,
        }
      ]
    ) ],
  declarations:   [ AppComponent,HomeComponent,BannerComponent],

  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">footerLink</a>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

---

home.component.ts

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <button routerLink="/banner">Banner</button>`
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

---

banner.component.ts

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <button routerLink="/banner">Banner</button>`
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

---

✔ If a user clicks on a banner button and then click the tab on the next('/banner') page. In that case, 'BannerLink' anchor should be a highlight.

✘ Currently clicking on the tab on next('/banner') page focusing FooterLink anchor tag

#### Edit

I found an issue,
this is happening because of `BrowserAnimationsModule`, If I replace with `BrowserModule` it works fine, now why this is happening with `BrowserAnimationsModule` module?

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720611/how-to-use-angular4-to-set-focus-by-element-id/46720813) ?

Comment: @jmb-mage I want to focus on tab click, not by default