# Set element focus using a directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to get an Angular Directive to control setting the focus on an element programmatically.

Here is what my directive looks like in the component html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="inputText" [myFocus]="isFocused">
```

Here is what my directive looks like:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myFocus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('myFocus') isFocused: boolean;

  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.isFocused) {   
      this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.hostElement.nativeElement).focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the component code I changed this:

```
this.isFocused = true;
```

The directive is included in the app.module.ts like so:

```
import { FocusDirective } from './directives/focus.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FocusDirective
  ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However the focus does not seem to get set when I do this.
I understand there have been some fairly big changes to how the Renderer2 works, and I assume I am getting something wrong with my step of setting the focus in the ngOnInit() method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus on element with binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307060/how-to-set-focus-on-element-with-binding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve using nativeElement.focus()

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myFocus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('myFocus') isFocused: boolean;

  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.isFocused) {   
      this.hostElement.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I should work. may ne you are doing something wrong. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307060/how-to-set-focus-on-element-with-binding

Comment: Try using ngOnChanges life cycle method. Updated the code

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya so basically a copy-paste of an existing answer uh?

Comment: No, i added the code based on feedback i validated and updated the code.

Comment: Angular team doesn't encourage manipulating DOM directly. It's prone to XSS attacks. You should be using Renderer2 instead

Comment: should you use blur() when isFocused is false ? looks like it's working without it but I'm wondering how is it working without it

Answer (score 2):

Simplified version of @Suresh Kumar Ariya's answer without using change detection. This will focus only when the `[myFocus]=value` directive switch to true.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myFocus]',
})
export class FocusDirective {
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}

  @Input()
  set myFocus(focus: boolean) {
    if (focus) {
      this.hostElement.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
}
```